# php email class that will display correct output on outlook 2007

Tags: php, email, class, outlook

Can anyone tell me of a php class that can send html based email on outlook express? I am using a class it words fine on yahoo, msn and gmail but when i try it on outlook it does not display correct output. I mean the email display on outlook is not correct.

Thanks,
-dizyn

Answer (score 1):

It's probably your HTML, not anything to do with the PHP.

[Outlook now uses Word to display HTML](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2007/01/10/microsoft-breaks-html-email-rendering-in-outlook/), and it's notoriously bad.

See [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201.aspx)

Comment: i'm not sure this applies to outlook express.

Comment: The title says outlook, the text says outlook and outlook express, so who knows what the OP is really asking about :)

Answer (score 0):

[phpmailer](http://www.empereur-team.com/) proved perfect for my needs. available on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it down to the HTML content or do you suspect incorrect mime-encoding?

I've used http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ and got emails working against 100s of email clients via Lyris' inbox tester.